# PHP "require" with constants

Tags: php, constants

I have two files: home.php and head.php. In home.php is this:

```
<?php
  define('FILE_TITLE', 'Home');
  define('STLYESHEET_1_HREF', 'css/home.css');
?>
<html>
  <?php require 'head.php' ?>
  <!-- Some HTML -->
</html>
```

And in head.php:

```
<head>
  <title><?php echo FILE_TITLE; ?></title>
  <?php if (defined('STYLESHEET_1_HREF')): ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo STYLESHEET_1_HREF ?>">
  <?php endif; ?>
  <!-- Some PHP&HTML -->
</head>
```

`FILE_TITLE` works fine, but it won't go into the if-statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change this line :
<?php if (defined('STYLESHEET_1_HREF')); ?>

Comment: @KishanPatel That's wrong. Semicolon ends the `if` block.

Comment: spelling mistake, define STLY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
define('STLYESHEET_1_HREF', 'css/home.css');

href="<?php echo STYLESHEET_1_HREF ?>">
```

you have a typo.

change `STLYESHEET_1_HREF` in the define, to `STYLESHEET_1_HREF` and it will work fine.

Comment: For typos, just post it as a comment and vote to close.

Comment: Ok, it works now. Those typos will once ruin my life.

Comment: Re typos: The lesson to learn here is to use a decent IDE. You'll get a lot fewer typos if your IDE is giving you an auto-complete suggestion on everything.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use

```
<?php
  const FILE_TITLE =  'Home';
  const STYLESHEET_1_HREF = 'css/home.css';
?>
```

and

```
<title>
  <?php echo !empty(FILE_TITLE) ? FILE_TITLE : 'Some Default Title' ; ?>
</title>
<?php if (!empty(STYLESHEET_1_HREF)): ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo STYLESHEET_1_HREF ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```